# Retrieve jinja2 template variables from python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm using `python` and `jinja2` to generate customized reports from the same data using templates (ex: Being able to export to `xml`, `json`, `txt` or custom structure without changing any line of the python script).

I would like the user to modify ONLY the template file to configure its report, and therefore use variables to define the filename and other parameters.

Example template:

```
{# HEADER -#}
{% set filename = 'custom-report.txt' -%}

{# BODY -#}
{% for item in items -%}
Date = {{ item["Date"] }}
Action = {{ item["Action"] }}
Result = {{ item["Result"] }}

{% endfor %}
```

From python, is it possible to retrieve the filename value ("`custom-report.txt`" in this case) so that I know what's the filename to be used ?

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT:**

For a better understanding, here is an example of what I expect from python:

```py
template = templateEnv.get_template(template_path)
rawoutput = template.render(items=items)

output_filename = template.getVariable('filename')

with open(output_filename, "w") as stream:
    stream.write(rawoutput)
```

Where the "getVariable" method is what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

You'd do that likewise you returned your `items` in your template. In your context just add a variable `filename = 'custom-report.txt' # or whatever you need` and on the rendering you just use `{{ filename }}` to display it.

A Simple example with `jinja2` package

```
import jinja2
t = jinja2.Template("This is the filename: {{ filename }}!")
print t.render(filename ="custom-report.txt")
```

The template could also be your file.

So you need python to read a variable from the template. That cannot be done without a framework i.e. `flask` that has a request object to pass values. A solution I suggest is to read your template in python and parse it to find the text you need. i.e.
With the above template given as is

```
template = templateEnv.get_template(template_path)
rawoutput = template.render(items=items)

output_filename = open('a.txt', 'r').read().split('{% set filename = \'')[1].split('\'')[0]
print(output_filename)

with open(output_filename, "w") as stream:
    stream.write(rawoutput)
```

That way you parse the whole template and split the filename. Not the best method but works if you keep a standard format.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use variables inside a template. The goal for me is just to parse the template from python and retrieve some variables contained in it, so that I can adapt the action that will follow the rendering.

Comment: I also updated my first post with an example, so you can better understand what I'm trying to do. The filename "custom-report.txt" is NOT known by the python script!

Comment: @SébastienMatton Take a look above.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the way I would have worked if there was no more elegant solution...But I'm still crossing my fingers and hoping there is a real solution that won't be affected by extra spaces, simple or double quotes,... :-)

Comment: Without a client-server framework passing variables that cannot be done because python renders the file with its own data, but the reverse cannot be done. Hope i helped.